# How do I read the information of a JTextField from a separate class using an ActionListener

Tags: java

The following code is within a class that has the buttons and checkboxes defined. The problem that I am having is with the lines "String text = txtField.getText();" and "chkAccount.withdraw(amount);".

I have a separate class file that defines the txtField and am trying to get the text that has been input into that box. The error I see is "cannot find symbol". I have looked into it but cant find information in depth enough to answer my question.

The second line refers to the object chkAccount which is derived from a separate class "Account" and instantiated in the main class of my program. The error for this is the same as the above.

```
//Button Listeners Class
    withdrawalBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Execute this code when the button is pressed
            if(checking.isSelected()) {
                String text = txtField.getText();
                int amount = Integer.parseInt(text);
                try {
                    chkAccount.withdraw(amount);
                } catch (InsufficientFunds ex) {
                    int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Balance too low" +
                            "or amount entered not an Interval of 20.", 
                            "Notice", messageType);
                }
                }
```

Comment: I'm guessing `txtField` and `chkAccount` are not visible in that context. I.e. they are defined in a separate class and I'm also guessing that `Button Listeners Class` is not inner class of `Main Class` / `Text field class`...

Comment: Yes that is correct. My file list is as follows. Account (contructor for account types), AutoTellerApp (main), AutoTellerPanel (brings the together BPanel and IOpanel to one object), BPanel (buttons and checkboxes), IOPanel (text fields), and  Frame.

Comment: Problem with your question is that there is a lot of irrelevant code, and not the things that are important, please read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of hard to reproduce if I don't just paste all of the files here so they can be loaded up, but I'm working with 6 different files. The questionable part is specifically related to the action listener. How would you suggest I go about giving information that can reproduce the problem when I am working with that many different files? I looked at your link and saw the bit about writing another program using minimal code, I will try that but with everything needing to be linked it's going to be somewhat complicated. Also thanks for the link and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what the code that you've provided is trying to do, but just based on the title of your question, I would recommend you have the class that you want the information to go to `extends ActionListener`, add an object of that type of class (the one that you had extend ActionListener) as an ActionListener to the JTextField, and then in the `actionPerformed` method (which you'll have to add, as the class now extends ActionListener) use `ActionEvent.getSource` (and cast) to get the JTextField! From there, you can extract the information that you need.

Comment: I am trying to build a simple atm style interface that withdraws, deposits, transfers, and shows a balance of a checking or savings account (automatically generated).
The action listener checks if a button is pressed, once the button is pressed, it checks to see if the checkbox for checking or savings account is selected (this is declared within the buttons class) and is then supposed to check the balance of either chkAccount or savAccount (instantiated in main class) and follow the function of the button that is pressed (deposit or withdraw etc.)